# Not able to send put request with postman

Tags: javascript, node.js

what I am sending is

```
http://localhost:3000/accounts?user_id=62139fbf-ce6a-4827-8fe8-f1c3197bff82
  // params
user_id   62139fbf-ce6a-4827-8fe8-f1c3197bff82
```

My Api in node Js inside account.js is

```
router.route('/:user_id').put(function(req, res) {
console.log("hello")
```

It works when I change the route to the following( i.e I remove the params user_id and also from the postman.

```
router.route('/').put(function(req, res) {
    console.log("efwe")
```

So the problem is with sending params any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your URL should be like -

http://localhost:3000/accounts/62139fbf-ce6a-4827-8fe8-f1c3197bff82

for route - `router.route('/accounts/:user_id').`

For query parameters you need to do something like this - http://localhost:3000/accounts?user_id=62139fbf-ce6a-4827-8fe8-f1c3197bff82

```
router.route("/accounts",function(req,res){
    var id = req.query.user_id; // Check syntax for framework you are using 
});
```